# How to map NHibernate variable table reference?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Having a table called `ChildTable` with 2 columns `SourceTable` and `SourceId` and some other tables `ParentTable1`, `ParentTable2`, etc.

The Id found in `SourceId` can be used to join to a parent table when the `SourceTable` has a value associated with that table (1 -> `ParentTable1`, 2 -> `ParentTable2`). For example, to get all the `ChildTable` rows which are associated to rows in `ParentTable1` it would be achieved with this query:

```
select *
from ChildTable ct
join ParentTable1 pt1
  on ct.SourceTable = 1 and ct.SourceId = pt1.Id
```

I would like to map those 2 `ChildTable` columns as 1 property per parent table: Parent1, Parent2,... so 1 of them would be not null and the rest of the parent properties would be null:

```
public class ChildClass
{
    public Parent1Class Parent1 { get; set; }
    public Parent2Class Parent2 { get; set; }
    public Parent3Class Parent3 { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Question is: how to write the mapping for this case (mapping by code if possible)?

Note: This is for mapping existing tables, refactoring the table schema is not a solution yet (but suggestions are welcome).

**Update**

For the purpose of querying it seems to be enough to map a ChildClass property Parent1 with:

```
ManyToOne(property => property.Parent1, map => map.Formula("(select pt1.Id from dbo.ParentTable1 pt1 where SourceTable = 1 and pt1.Id = SourceId)"));
```

and the Children collection of Parent1Class with:

```
mapper.Where("SourceTable = 1");
```

For update/insert it is probably achievable using accessors, will post an update later.

Comment: In your desired ChildClass are all the properties of type Parent1Class, or are they Parent1/2/3Class?

Comment: Ah, thanks for noticing, it was a typo, they are different types.

Comment: You have a condition where you want to filter a many-to-one mapping with a where clause - based on the SourceId. Can you confirm that SourceIds are fixed? It would seem there is an unresolved [jira](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2874) for this.

Comment: That issue seems to be looking for a solution to my problem. What do you mean by `SourceId` being fixed?

Comment: Normally the join would have been done with a parent using only an ID pointing at the parent primary key. In my case the ID will point to a different table depending on the `SourceTable` column.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure - fixed meaning that for one FK table (e.g. `ParentClass3`) the `SourceId` will be always and everywhere the same (e.g. 3) :). I.e. there will never be the case that there are two rows with `SourceId` == 3 and 4 which both should point to `ParentClass3` nor the case that in one database `SourceId` 3 points to `ParentClass3` and in another to some other parent class. Obviously, then, yes, the jira is exactly what is the solution.

Comment: There can be duplicate values in `SourceId` column, but they have to be unique for each `SourceTable`. Basically the combination of `SourceTable` and `SourceId` is unique. You could have SourceId = 1 for 3 rows if each SourceId would point to a different parent table (ParentTable1, ParentTable2, ParentTable3)

Comment: Clear. But `SourceId == 1` means always and everywhere this is `ParentClass1`. Upvote means yes :)

Comment: `SourceId` confers no meaning except that it is an Id pointing to some table. `SourceTable` value is what tells the Id to which table it refers to. Example: `SourceId` = 1 and `SourceTable` = 1 => row is a child of ParentTable1, `SourceId` = 1 and `SourceTable` = 2 => row is a child of ParentTable2, and so on.

Comment: Ah, got confused, you can have non-unique `SourceId` for the same `SourceTable`. Otherwise it would not be many to one.

Comment: So, 3 rows with `SourceId` = 1 and `SourceTable` = 1 means they are a child collection of row with Id 1 from ParentTable1.

Comment: Sorry, I confused `SourceId` and `SourceTable`. I meant to refer to `SourceTable` in the comments.

Comment: @h.alex Posted an update on what I figured out until now.

Comment: Or this one https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3189

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [`Any`](http://notherdev.blogspot.ch/2012/02/mapping-by-code-any.html)?

Class:

```
public class ChildClass
{
    public virtual ParentBase Parent { get; set; }

    // beware of proxies when casting... this may not work like this
    public Parent1Class Parent1 { get { return Parent as Parent1Class; } }
    public Parent2Class Parent2 { get { return Parent as Parent2Class; } }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Mapping:

```
Any(x => x.Parent, typeof(int), m =>
{
    m.IdType<int>();
    m.MetaType<int>();

    m.MetaValue(1, typeof(Parent1));
    m.MetaValue(2, typeof(Parent2));

    m.Columns(
      id => id.Name("SourceId"), 
      classRef => classRef.Name("SourceTable"));
});
```

There is also `many-to-any`, which maps collections of any types into a relation table.

When using it in a query, you can check the `.class`, or use a subquery:

HQL:

```
select *
from ChildTable ct join Parent
where pt1.class = Parent1
```

or

```
select * 
from ChildTable ct 
Where ct.Parent in (from Parant2 p where p.Property = 'Hugo')
```

Comment: Thank you. Updating the parent property and querying with LINQ using `child.Parent is Parent1Class` works. Can't get `.Fetch(_ => _.Parent)` to work as it throws *An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Type.AnyType' to type 'NHibernate.Type.ComponentType'.* Same error for projecting with `.Select(...)`. Will probably post another question.

Comment: Same problem as above when trying to use cast/as to be able to make conditions on the Parent in a LINQ Where clause.

Comment: Hi @RăzvanFlaviusPanda
could you resolve this cast issue?